# lua split string and save in lua table

Tags: string, lua

Is there an way to split an string and save it into an table like this:

```
str = "23 = John, 45 = Karl, 6 = Chloe, 34 = Sarah" 

--[[ 23     John
     45     Karl
     6      Chloe
     34     Sarah]]
```

I want the numbers to be the keys and the Names to be the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt this code:

```
for k,v in str:gmatch("(%d+)%s*=%s*(%a+)") do
    print(k,v)
end
```

This assumes that the names are composed of letters only.

Comment: Do you now the pattern if it is like :string = " 10 = Hello_World, 4 = Hello_World_Good_Bye"

Comment: @Glupschi read [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 6.4.1 Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1)  try it yourself or you won't learn